# Как сделать линии рандомного цвета в particle.js

Tags: javascript

https://dollarakshay.com/particles.html
Как сделать так,но чтобы мышь создавала линии от точек к ней,а не отталкивала точки?

Comment: https://codepen.io/IbnShaalan/pen/RZKaBE?q=particle+js&limit=all&type=type-pens

Comment: разноцветные,а не обычные -_-.Тему то читай. Каждая своего цвета